# Getting "cannot read proper 'popperRef' of undefined" while adding a tooltip for cytoscape(cy)nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js, popper.js

Getting "cannot read proper 'popperRef' of undefined" while adding a tooltip for cytoscape(cy)nodes. I am using Vue.js and Cytoscape.js. Not

```
mounted() {    
  cytoscape.use(popper)
  this.addTooltip()
}
methods : { 
addTooltip() {
  let makeTippy = function (nodeTemp, node) {
        return tippy( node.popperRef(), {
          content: function(){
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = text;
            return div;
          },
          trigger: 'manual',
          arrow: true,
          placement: 'bottom',
          hideOnClick: false,
          interactive: true
        } ).tooltips[0]
      }

       var nodes = this.cy.nodes();
       for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
           var tippy = makeTippy(nodes[i]);
           tippy.show();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-popper#usage-with-tippyjs

If you have trouble making things within your app and you're not comfortable with using a debugger, then you should try to reproduce your issue outside of your app in s simple demo that's easier for your to reason about.

Here are materials for learning how to use the browser's debugger: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/